# concatenate date and time in odoo 9.0

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-7, odoo-9

I have two fields as shown below.

```
>  appo_date = fields.Date(string="Appointment Date")
>  appo_time = fields.Float(string="Appointment Time")
```

I need to concatenate this two fields. For that i wrote a function as shown below.

```
def _combine(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        values = {}
        for id in ids:
            rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
            values[id] = {}
            values[id] = '%f - %f' % (rec.appo_date, rec.appo_time)
        return values
```

And called that function in a separate field as shown below.

```
appo_date_and_time = fields.Char(compute='_combine', string='Appointment Date/Time', arg=('appo_date','appo_time'), method=True)
```

These fields are called in xml files

```
<field name="appo_date"/>
<field name="appo_time"/>
<field name="appo_date_and_time"/>
```

I am getting an error as

```
TypeError: _combine() takes at least 6 arguments (5 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with Odoo 9. So It's advisable to do practice with new api.

Try with this code:

```
@api.multi
def _combine(self):
    if self.appo_date and self.appo_time:
        self.appo_date_and_time = '%f - %f' % (self.appo_date, self.appo_time)
    elif self.appo_date:
        self.appo_date_and_time = str(self.appo_date)
    elif self.appo_time:
        self.appo_date_and_time = str(self.appo_time)
    else
        self.appo_date_and_time = 'No Date and Time set'
```

Comment: thank you.. but i have date_field (appo_date = fields.Date(string="Appointment Date")) what datatype should i give to get date

Comment: Date datatype is work fine. It will prompt user to enter date.

Comment: hey, am getting in this format "2016-05-19 9.000000" How to arrange date and time?